# Firebird total column

Tags: firebird

I have a query that I am struggling with. The problem I have is that I would like it to just display a total of column `variancevalue` as a result.

```
SELECT
  DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DepartmentName,
  SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubDeptName,
  SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubSubDeptName,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Onhand,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT) StockCount,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Variance,
  sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM
  STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
  INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
  INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT ON STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
WHERE
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete'
GROUP BY
  1,2,3
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION, SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION, SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION
```

Can this be done and if so how would I do that?

Comment: If you're looking for a single value as your output (1 row w/ 1 column), why not ... `select sum(...) VarianceValue from ... `? (no `group by`, no `order by`); I'm assuming there's more to this than what you've described and if so, I'd recommend editing the question to add more details as to what you want and why the current query doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: Does firebird support grouping sets?

Comment: @Lennart Firebird does not support grouping sets.

Comment: Please include sample data and the expected result for that sample data.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the entire output of your current query with just one single-column row holding the total across the `VarianceValue` column of the original output, then just take the current query and remove

- the `GROUP BY` clause,
- the `ORDER BY` clause,
- the left joins,
- and all `SELECT` terms but one (the last one):

```
SELECT
  DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DepartmentName,
  SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubDeptName,
  SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubSubDeptName,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Onhand,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT) StockCount,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Variance,
  sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM
  STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
  INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
  INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT ON STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
WHERE
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete'
GROUP BY
  1,2,3
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION, SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION, SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION
```

That is, without the parts struck through the query should look like this (just to make it absolutely unambiguous and copy-paste-friendly):

```
SELECT
  sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM
  STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
  INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
  INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
WHERE
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete';
```

It is quite possible that the inner joins are unnecessary too. They probably need to stay if they can affect the result. And they *can* affect the result if either of these is true:

- `STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK` is nullable and/or may contain values not found in `STOCK.INTRECNO`;
- `STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION` is nullable and/or may contain values not found in `LOCATION.INTRECNO`.

If you have foreign key relationships in place, then what matters is just the nullability of `STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK` and `STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION`. Now if both columns are *not* nullable and the referential integrity is guaranteed, then you should be able to get the same result by reducing the query to just this:

```
SELECT
  sum((STOCKCOUNT - QTYONHAND) * CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM
  STOCKTAKELIST
WHERE
  ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKCOUNT <> QTYONHAND AND
  Status = 'Complete';
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Is there maybe a way that I can get it to give me multiple values as in 2 or more date ranges

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT
  DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DepartmentName,
  SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubDeptName,
  SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubSubDeptName,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Onhand,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT) StockCount,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Variance,
  sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
  INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
  INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT 
      ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE
     AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT 
      ON STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE 
     AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE 
     AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
WHERE
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete'
GROUP BY 1,2,3

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'Total' AS DepartmentName,
  'Total' AS SubDeptName,
  'Total' AS SubSubDeptName,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Onhand,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT) StockCount,
  sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Variance,
  sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
FROM STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
  INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
  INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT 
      ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE
     AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
  LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT 
      ON STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE 
     AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE 
     AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
WHERE
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
  STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete'

ORDER BY DepartmentName, SubDeptName, subSubDeptName
```

According to [Documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html) CTE:s are supported. You could put your query in a CTE:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT
      DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DepartmentName,
      SUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubDeptName,
      SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS SubSubDeptName,
      sum(STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Onhand,
      sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT) StockCount,
      sum(STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) Variance,
      sum((STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT - STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND) * STOCKTAKELIST.CostPrice) VarianceValue
    FROM STOCKTAKELIST STOCKTAKELIST
      INNER JOIN Stock STOCK ON STOCKTAKELIST.INTRECNO_STOCK = STOCK.INTRECNO
      INNER JOIN Location LOCATION ON STOCK.INTRECNO_LOCATION = LOCATION.INTRECNO
      LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
      LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT 
          ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE
         AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
      LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT 
          ON STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE 
         AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE 
         AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
    WHERE
      STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate >= '01 Jun 2018' AND
      STOCKTAKELIST.ListCreate <= '10 Jun 2018 23:59:59' AND
      STOCKTAKELIST.IncludeInCount = 'Yes' AND
      STOCKTAKELIST.STOCKCOUNT <> STOCKTAKELIST.QTYONHAND AND
      STOCKTAKELIST.Status = 'Complete'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT DepartmentName, SubDeptName, SubSubDeptName
     , Onhand, StockCount, Variance, VarianceValue
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' as DepartmentName
     , 'Total' as SubDeptName
     , 'Total' as SubSubDeptName
     , sum(Onhand), sum(StockCount), sum(Variance), sum(VarianceValue)
FROM T
```